# Apache commons csv

Tags: java, apache, csv, apache-commons-csv

I can't understand the core of apache commons csv library. 
Could you advice a method I should use when I want to get columns by header name from csv file by apache-commons-csv?
For example, I have such csv file:

```
Delays, Computation time, Communication time
0., 500000, 10
20., 563210, 20
55., 546541., 23.
12., 465487., 23.
45., 456547., 28.
87., 985458., 56.
47., 456778., 45.
```

I want to get arrays: double[] delays, double[] compTime, double[] commTime consist of values from csv.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void parseInputCSV() throws IOException {
final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputFile.toURL().openStream(), "UTF-8");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(reader);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String first = record.get("FIRST_COLUMN");
    String second = record.get("SECOND_COLUMN");
    // all other columns
}
```

}

Comment: How can I get array by column name? =(

Comment: An array as a csv element??? Please post in the question a couple of rows of your csv file

Comment: I've updated question.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation :

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
  String lastName = record.get("Last Name");
  String firstName = record.get("First Name");
}
```

You'll get for each row the cell corresponding to the column name. (here lastName and firstName are not used and are deleted at each iteration, sure).

Comment: Just algorithm here, take 3 arrays, for each row, add cells to their array.... This is not apache commons here. Just an algorithm.